creating https to http proxy server
i have a ubuntu server and i want to setup a proxy server on him so he will route all https requests he recieve (GET or POST) to another http site and then return the response back to the origin at the https source.
i will glad to the shortest and easiest way as i dont good at network servers. i can use python or npm but i can't use nginx. also, my port 80 is in use, so i need the usage of another port.
i have a domain to my ubuntu, and i want to use it with it.
my environment is local without internet, will it raise a problem with https cert?
thanks!!!
i tried doing it with chatGPT, GEMINI, COPILOT etc with python scripts but they didnt do it right so i got many errors and i didn't know if it's becuase of the 1st site or my server.
